# BCS: Proof of gap existence without mean field approximation

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity

In textbook treatment of the BCS theory, by taking the **mean field approximation,** we get a quadratic hamiltonian, which can be exactly and easily solved (by invoking a Bogoliubov transform of the fermionic operators). In this way, we get a finite gap for the single particle excitations.

What if we do not invoke the mean field approximation, so that the hamiltonian contains the quartic (interaction) terms?

Can we still prove rigorously that the 1st excited state of the **many-body system** is gapped?

Comment: Starting from the quartic Hamiltonian (and assume that no electromagnetic field is present), the many-body spectrum is not gapped. There are gapless Goldstone modes. There is a single particle gap, i.e. if you add an electron, there is a gap.